# Algorithm to calculate pairs from a class of n students for w weeks

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, sports-league-scheduling-problem

I am searching for an algorithm to calculate pairs from a class of n (a list of student names) for w weeks, so that a student never coöperates with the same student in two different weeks. Assume that n is even.

Example:

class: students 1,2,3,4

weeks: 3

- schedule for week 1: (1,2), (3,4)
- schedule for week 2: (1,3), (2,4)
- schedule for week 3: (2,3), (1,4)

I figured that w has to be smaller than or equal to n - 1 because every student can maximally coöperate with n - 1 others. But I don't know if there are always n - 1 solutions. If there are, I would like to see the algoritm that generates these n - 1 solutions in a none-brute force way.

Is there a name for this problem and a common algorithm I should look at?

Comment: Is n even? (Or if n is odd, a student has to be left out. Is this okay? Is it okay when n is odd?)

Comment: Even is good enough for me, but if the algorithm can handle uneven classes and takes care, for example that one student never has to work alone mor than once, all the better.

Comment: Ok, then the [Wikipedia section on scheduling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Round-robin_tournament&oldid=432980993#Scheduling_algorithm) is your answer. Just change "plays" to "cooperates with". It does guarantee that there are n-1 rounds (i.e., w=n-1 in your question) and that when there are an odd number of students, each student works alone (= plays against the dummy player) exactly once.

Comment: FYI: I implemented the algorithm in Clojure here https://gist.github.com/1027851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it is equivalent to a [round robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament).

Comment: It's better to include the algorithm here, as links can go dead. (Yes even Wikipedia, where the section describing the algorithm may get deleted for having no citations, etc.)